# Decision trees in R, predicting one choice

Tags: r, dataset, classification

I'm doing a tutorial with iris dataset on decision trees in R. Here is my code for the basic tutorial.

```
library(rpart)
install.packages('rpart.plot')
library(rpart.plot)

s = sample(150,100)

iris_train = iris[s,]
iris_test = iris[-s,]

dtm = rpart(Species~.,iris_train, method="class")

rpart.plot(dtm, type=4, extra=101)

p = predict(dtm,iris_test,type="class")
table(iris_test[,5],p)
```

The table line gives me:

```
                 setosa versicolor virginica
    setosa         12          0         0
    versicolor      0         18         0
    virginica       0          3        17
```

How would I go about if I am only interestted in the prediction of Virginica? Is there a possibility to merge the values of the rest so that I get a binary classification of Virginica vs Versicolor + Setosa?

Comment: You could create a new `Species` variable in which you have a category for `virginica` and a category for both `versicolor` and `setosa`. Then you could redo your analysis using the new `Species` variable.

Comment: a simple `ifelse` statement will do this in one line for you

Answer (score 0):

you can do what you want like that

```
library(rpart)
install.packages('rpart.plot')
library(rpart.plot)

s = sample(150,100)
class <- which(iris$Species %in% c("versicolor","setosa")) 

####################################
new_species = rep("virginica",nrow(iris))

new_species[class] <- "vers_seto"

iris$new_species <- new_species
####################################
iris_train = iris[s,-5]    # -5 Delete the old column Species (column number 5) 


iris_test = iris[-s,-5]



dtm = rpart(new_species~.,iris_train, method="class")

rpart.plot(dtm, type=4, extra=101)

p = predict(dtm,iris_test,type="class")
table(iris_test[,5],p)
```